# Align mat-icon button to top right for close button

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular13

I have a problem with aligning my close icon button to top right of my dialog box.

app-iconbutton:

```
<button
  mat-icon-button
  class="iconbutton"
  [ngStyle]="{
    'background-color': backcolor
  }"
  (click)="onClick()"
>
  <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{ 'color': iconcolor }">{{ icontype }}</mat-icon>
</button>
```

dialog box:

```
<div>
  <app-iconbutton
    backcolor="white"
    iconcolor="darkblue"
    icontype="close"
    class="closeicon"
  ></app-iconbutton>
</div>
<div class="dialogbox">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title class="title">{{ title }}</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <p class="content">{{ content }}</p>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="onYesClick()" cdkFocusInitial>
      {{ confirmtext }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my css, I've tried, but it aligns right itself with the title which is not what I want

```
.closeicon {
  float: right; 
}
```

Also this, which makes my icon button outside of dialog box instead relative to screen, which is not what I want either.

```
.closeicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Can someone help me with this css? Sorry, my first try with Angular, so I don't know many things...

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually edited my app-iconbutton to fit inside dialogbox div and set my dialog box's position to relative and closeicon css to be like this:

```
.closeicon {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -20px;
}
```

Not my preferred solution but it works...